# Output a Multi-array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am struggling to output this multi-array, I have tried looping through using a for each loop ... This is what I see when I insert a break point, which the array 'response' is storing, so how would I go about writing these to the console

```
response    Count = 6   System.Collections.Generic.List<int[]>
[0] {int[1]}    int[]
     [0]    1577    int
[1] {int[0]}    int[]
[2] {int[0]}    int[]
[3] {int[0]}    int[]
[4] {int[0]}    int[]
[5] {int[6]}    int[]
     [0]    31  int
     [1]    246 int
     [2]    448 int
     [3]    663 int
     [4]    864 int
     [5]    1734    int
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (int[] subList in response)
{
    foreach (int item in subList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Using for loop:

```
for (int subListIndex = 0; subListIndex < response.Count; subListIndex++)
{
    for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < response[subListIndex].Length; itemIndex++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response[subListIndex][itemIndex]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The 'item' comes up with an error stating that it does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @user: it is a typo `in item` instead of `int item` no fixed.

Comment: Thanks, however the second loop you added worked a treat... Thank you very much